# Best method for transitioning height with unknown / dynamic content height?

Tags: javascript

I've seen janky CSS solutions and some overly complicated javascript solutions, but I'm wondering the best js and / or css3 technique to achieve this:

1. click a button `'.contentToggle'` which loads content into a `'.container'`.
2. transition said `'.container'`'s height from zero to the height of the just-loaded content.
3. do this without jerks, flashes such that content blocks below the `'.container'` slide elegantly down and up as you toggle the content loader.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/n3wudoge/)

```
var content = '<div class="content"></div>';
var container = $('.container');
var toggler = $('.toggler');

toggler.click(function() {
  if (container.hasClass('open')) {
    container.removeClass('open');
    container.html(undefined);
    container.slideUp('slow');
  } else {
    container.addClass('open');
    container.html(content);
    container.slideDown('slow');
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show us code that you've already tried?

Comment: The code base is a behemoth, complex PHP mess, but I'll try to create a fiddle.

Comment: I updated my question with a fiddle. You'll notice it works fine after the first toggle because it has the height, but the first click, it can't slide down to an unknown height.

Comment: This is often done by animating the `max-height` instead.